# Change tab close button to be a custom image?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a browser which looks like this:

[image: custom qt py browser]

It is working great. However, I want to change that red X next to the tab name to be a nicer icon. Is this possible to change? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: [Customizing QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).

Comment: @musicamante thanks so much for the help! This solved my issue- if you want to post this as an answer I would gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `QStyleSheets` which is the easiest way.

```
QTabBar::close-button {
    image: url(close.png)
    subcontrol-position: left;
}
QTabBar::close-button:hover {
    image: url(close-hover.png)
}
```

Or if you wanted to customize each tab, or wanted more control over what the button does you could create  `QToolButton`  connect it to an action and then assign it to a tab with the [`QTabBar.setTabButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabbar.html#setTabButton) method.

```
tab_bar.setTabButton(0, QTabBar.ButtonPosition.RightSide, close_btn)
```